I can't get data from a txt file
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10
#define PI 3.14159265359

int i,j;

double const X0=5,Y0=5,FI=0.7854;//FI in rads
double fi=FI*180/PI;//fi in degress

struct exp_point{
    double x,y;
    double x1,y1;
    int line;
};


int main(){
    double d,x,y,x1,y1;
    i=0,j=0;
    FILE *fp;
    
    if ((fp=fopen("points2D_uni.txt","r"))==NULL)
{ printf("error reading file....\n");
exit(1);
}
else{
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%lf  %lf",&x,&y);
        printf("x=%lf   y=%lf\n",x,y);
        x1=(x-X0)*cos(fi)+(y-Y0)*sin(fi);
        y1=(y-Y0)*cos(fi)+(x-X0)*sin(fi);
        d=pow(pow(x1-X0,2)+pow(y1-Y0,2),0.5);
        if(d>10.0)
            i++;
        else j++;
    }
fclose(fp);
    printf("i=%d   j=%d\n",i,j);
    
    struct exp_point *lim;
    struct exp_point *arr;
    
    lim=(struct exp_point *)calloc(i,sizeof(exp_point));
    arr=(struct exp_point *)calloc(j,sizeof(exp_point));
    printf("%d",i+j);
}
    
    
    return 0;   
}

I need to get some data from a txt file containing points in a coordinates system but when i print them all are 0 and the file scan never ends. I have tried both unicode file and with tabs. In the file with tabs it gets the first number without the demical points and after that all the other data are displayed as 0.0000

Can you provide an example of your input file?

let me try to upload it

Please see Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong? That is not what feof() does, you could control the loop with the return value from fscanf() (it should be checked anyway).

the first number is 8,555253262 and the second is 24,37160676 but only 8.000000 and y=0.00000 is printed

Maybe fscanf is expecting . instead of , in your numbers?

@George your code is not locale aware. The 8,55... is using the German decimal comma. Your code is assuming default locale and a decimal point. That is why fscanf finds the comma as a first illegal character, stops parsing the number and stores 8 in your x. Since the subsequent string does not match your pattern (because it is starting with a comma), the next value will be zero (in y). Plus I think your coordinates are separated by line breaks in your file but you do not read them in your loop.

I replaced all the , with . and there is still an issue

"I replaced all the , with . and there is still an issue". Which issue? Your file is probably in UNICODE format. What is your platform?

Yes my file is in UNICODE forman and i use devC++

@George which platform? Windows/Linux/... ? And yes your file should not be in UNICODE format. Convert it with your favorite text editor. I can't give more hints since I don't know which platform you're on.

You have //fi in degress but are passing it to sin(fi) and cos(fi). That should be sin(FI) and cos(FI)? Anyway, if those a constant value you could precalculate them outside the loop.

...and it looks like a rotation of coordinates by angle by FI around point (5, 5). If so, the sign of one of the sin(FI) terms in the expression may be wrong.

Here is a small correction and suggestion
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265359

// Definition of the struct exp_point
struct exp_point {
    double x, y;
    double x1, y1;
    int line;
};

int main() {
    double X0 = 5, Y0 = 5, FI = 0.7854; // FI in radians
    double fi = FI; // Using FI directly since it is already in radians
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double d, x, y, x1, y1;
    FILE *fp;

    // Provide the absolute path to the file
    const char *file_path = "/ABSOLUTE/PATH/file.txt"; // Replace with your actual file path

    // Attempt to open the file
    if ((fp = fopen(file_path, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Reading the file until the end
    while (fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf", &x, &y) == 2) {
        printf("Read values: x = %lf, y = %lf\n", x, y);
        
        // Applying transformation
        x1 = (x - X0) * cos(fi) + (y - Y0) * sin(fi);
        y1 = (y - Y0) * cos(fi) - (x - X0) * sin(fi);
        
        // Calculating distance using hypot
        d = hypot(x1 - X0, y1 - Y0);
        
        if (d > 10.0)
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose(fp);

    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);

    // Allocate memory for exp_point structures
    struct exp_point *lim = (struct exp_point *)calloc(i, sizeof(struct exp_point));
    struct exp_point *arr = (struct exp_point *)calloc(j, sizeof(struct exp_point));
    
    if (lim == NULL || arr == NULL) {
        perror("Error allocating memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Total points processed: %d\n", i + j);

    // Free allocated memory
    free(lim);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}

Get absolute path
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        printf("Current working directory: %s\n", cwd);
    } else {
        perror("getcwd() error");
        return 1;
    }

    // The rest of your code...
}

